# Bootstrap column-set not shown correctly

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, jsf

why is the second column not show at the right side of the first column?
Currently it is shown below the first column set.

```
<!-- ZUSAMMENFASSUNG -->
<b:row>
  <h:form>
    <b:column col-lg="6" col-md="6" col-xs="12">
      <h2>Zusammenfassung</h2>
      <b:panelGrid columns="2">
        <b:navCommandLink value="6 Neuanträge gesamt"></b:navCommandLink>
        <b:navCommandLink value="KEINE Vorkomnisse"></b:navCommandLink>
        <b:navCommandLink value="3 Zuordungen zu vorhandenen AVS"></b:navCommandLink>
      </b:panelGrid>
    </b:column>
  </h:form>
  <h:form>
    <b:column col-lg="6" col-md="6" col-xs="12">
      <b:panelGrid columns="2" colSpans="5,7">
        <h:outputText value="Weitere Einstellungen, Ansichten bezüglich der Zusammenfassung können hier geändert werden" />
      </b:panelGrid>
    </b:column>
  </h:form>
</b:row>
```

Comment: Put the `h:form` inside the `b:column` so that you have `row/column/form`

Comment: thanks but same problem

Comment: Did you place your rows inside a container (see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)? And I guess this is GWT-Bootstrap, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i makes no sense but i solved the problem like this one:

```
    <b:container>
    <!-- ZUSAMMENFASSUNG -->
    <b:row>
        <b:column col-lg="6" col-md="6" col-xs="12">
            <h:form>
                <h2>Zusammenfassung</h2>
                <b:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <b:navCommandLink value="6 Neuanträge gesamt"></b:navCommandLink>
                    <b:navCommandLink value="KEINE Vorkomnisse"></b:navCommandLink>
                    <b:navCommandLink value="3 Zuordungen zu vorhandenen AVS"></b:navCommandLink>
                </b:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </b:column>
    </b:row>
    <b:column col-lg="6" col-md="6" col-xs="12">
        <h:form>
            <b:panelGrid columns="2" colSpans="5,7">
                <h:outputText
                    value="Weitere Einstellungen, Ansichten bezüglich der Zusammenfassung können hier geändert werden" />
            </b:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </b:column>
</b:container>
```

Comment: Au contraire, it makes a lot of sense. Bootstrap's grid system requires rows to be placed inside a container. Just take a look at the docs.